# Electron：Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: electron

I wrote a program with electron framework, it is normal to run directly in the development stage, but after packaging, when running the exe file, electron window is all white, only the default menu.
I checked devtool and got an error：

```
Not allowed to load local resource: 
file:///D:/MyProgramProjects/webstromProject/vue/electron-vite-demo-1/dist/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar/renderer/src/index/clipboard.html
```

[The electron window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUUxb.png)
please help me,how to do. **except set webSecurity = false;**, I need the security policy.

this is my code.
main.js:

```js
mainWindow.loadFile('src/renderer/src/index/' + url + '.html')
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "electron-vite-demo-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Electron application with Vue",
  "main": "./out/main/main.js",
  "author": "wule.sapce",
  "homepage": "https://www.electronjs.org",
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix",
    "start": "electron-vite preview",
    "dev": "electron-vite dev",
    "build": "electron-vite build",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build:win": "npm run build && electron-builder --win --config",
    "build:mac": "npm run build && electron-builder --mac --config",
    "build:linux": "npm run build && electron-builder --linux --config"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/preload": "^2.0.0",
    "@electron-toolkit/utils": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config": "^1.0.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "electron": "^25.6.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3",
    "electron-vite": "^1.0.27",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  }
}
```

[this my code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwEk3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the incorrect file. It should be `win.loadFile('dist/YourApp/YourIndexFile.html)`

So you should 1st build your angular application in production then in your dist folder there your can find the built files. Now you need to point to that html file in the dist folder.

Electron builder takes your built angular code and creates an executable using those files.

Also, ensure that the *main* parameter in your **package.json** point to the dist folder's main.js

Comment: I tried what you did and found my mistake, and then I found out that the root cause was that the html I had written wasn't being packaged.
Thank you!